# Calling stored procedures in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have searched documentation and tried google that, but I did not find a straight answer to the question:

**How can I call a stored procedure in Sequelize?**

I have searched the documentation of Sequelize but I have even not found a trace of the word "procedure" in that.

The closest I got was this bug-report-turned-feature-request:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/959

Quoting from the link:

*What I imagine would be awesome:*

```
sequelize.query('CALL calculateFees();').success(
    function (settingName1, settingName2, settingName3, users) {
});
```

They mention that it is possible to call stored procedures, but the syntax is not provided.

**Can anyone give me an example with the proper syntax?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Call SP with parameters in Sequelize

```
sequelize
  .query('CALL login (:email, :pwd, :device)', 
        {replacements: { email: "me@jsbot.io", pwd: 'pwd', device: 'android', }})
  .then(v=>console.log(v));
```

Comment: and where can I define this function? Using it as a prototype function in Model, I am not able to call it outside of model, e.g. in the controller.  Otherwise if I use sequelize in the controller itself, it says sequelize is not defined, Is it a good practice to define sequelize in the controller. ? I usually don't see it anywhere. If not what is the best way to define a custom query using sequelize?

Comment: @RameshPareek you can access Model.sequelize , I'm not sure about the syntax but you can debug the Model prototype, you'll find the sequelize. also you can directly import sequelize from npm

Answer (score 10):

Change `success` to `spread` and you're good to go. Note that this will only work on sequlize 2.0

Comment: So there's no dedicated function for calling the stored procedure just the raw query (with the change of `success` to `spread`)?

Answer (score 4):

sequalise queries return promises so below is how i query stored procedures.

```
sequelize.query('CALL calculateFees();').then(function(response){
     res.json(response);
    }).error(function(err){
       res.json(err);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I am sure, you may also need to get output from stored procedure. Here is a code including output value from procedure, using sequelize:

```js
models.sequelize.query('DECLARE @outParam1 INT, @outParam2 INT EXEC procedureName @param1=:param, @outParam1 = @outParam1 output, @outParam2 = @outParam2 output SELECT @outParam1 AS "outParam1", @outParam2 AS "outParam2"',
    {
    replacements:
    {
        param: 123
        },
        type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.EXEC
    }).spread(result => {
    if (result)
    {
        console.log("\nInside result : " + JSON.stringify(result));
        //return response here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a **MSSQL** stored procedure accepting two **DATETIME** parameters, this worked for me:

```
db.query('EXEC STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME :startDate, :endDate',
        { replacements: { startDate: moment(payload.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), endDate: moment(payload.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')},
          raw: true }
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed the stored procedure with the EXEC Key word.

```
sequelize
.query('EXEC getData :@param1', { replacements: { @param1: 'Test'}, type:sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
.then(data => /*Do something with the data*/)
.catch(error => /*Do something with the error*/)
```

Comment: Your doing it incorrectly it should look like this EXEC getData @param1=:param1', { replacements: { @param1: 'Test'}

Answer (score 0):

**Call SP with multiple parameters in Sequelize**

I am using await also.

```
const existing = await db.sequelize.query(`exec Fetch_Details ${AlphaCode},${Id}`, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
if (existing.length>=0) {
  res.send({
    status: "OK",
    message: "Records found!",
    result: existing,
  });
}
else{
  res.send({
    status: 404,
    message: "Not Found!"
    
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had trouble implementing on mysql and sequalize 6.32 version , seems there is a bug with result and metadata sequence:

```
new Sequalize(db, user, pass, { dialect: 'mysql', dialectOptions: { multipleStatements: true } }
```

My Mysql procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_movie`(
    IN maxFail INT,
    IN rrender VARCHAR(255),
    OUT attemptId INT,
    OUT rmovie_id INT,
   )
BEGIN

   SELECT id, movie_id INTO attemptId, rmovie_id FROM `movie_attempts` WHERE `fail_count` < maxFail AND `render` = rrender FOR UPDATE;
   UPDATE `movie_attempts` SET `status`='processing' WHERE `id`=attemptId;
   
END
```

and Typescript sequalize code:

```
const [, results] = // notice its not const [results, metadata]
      await Database.instance.sequelize.query(
        "CALL get_movie(:maxFail, :renderer, @attemptId, @movie_id); SELECT @attemptId AS id, @movie_id AS movie_id;", 
        {
          replacements: { maxFail: 3, renderer: "myname" },
          type: QueryTypes.SELECT
        });

console.log("\nInside result : " + JSON.stringify(results));
```