# Calling stored procedure in sequalize passing in a parameter

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

I'm trying to call a stored procedure passing in a parameter as shown below. However, I know my syntax is off and I don't see any examples doing this, either in the docs or unit tests.

```
model.sequelize.query('CALL truncate_tables(\'appuser\');')
  .then(function (response) {
    done();
  }).error(function (err) {
    done(err);
});
```

suggestions?

I started off looking at this link. [Calling stored procedures in Sequelize.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280785/calling-stored-procedures-in-sequelize-js)

Additional info:

here is the error I am seeing

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "CALL"
```

and here is the sp

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_tables(username character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    statements CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
    WHERE tableowner = username AND schemaname = 'public';
BEGIN
FOR stmt IN statements LOOP
    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) || ' CASCADE;';
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? If `appuser` is intended to be a string, the syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenLanger, I just updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are using PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL calls procedures with a syntax which is different from the other DBMS like MySQL or IBM Informix. It does not `CALL` the procedure but instead `SELECT`s from the stored procedure. A reference may be found at https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/41F009EA.6050401%40us.michelin.com.

Maybe this code would thus work:

```
model.sequelize.query('SELECT truncate_tables(\'appuser\');')
  .then(function (response) {
    done();
  }).error(function (err) {
    done(err);
});
```