# How to call stored proc in postgres using sequelize passing json parameter

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new to postgresql and sequelize ORM. 
I am trying to call a stored procedure which inserts data to a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_eoi(
obj json)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'sql' AS $BODY$
    INSERT INTO public."tbl_eoi" ("SE_CUST_ID", "SE_VENDOR_ID", "SE_VENUE_ID")
    SELECT (rec->>'custId')::integer, (rec->>'vendorId')::integer, (rec->>'venueId')::integer FROM
    json_array_elements(obj-> 'data')rec $BODY$;
```

Json input passed from node application

```
{ custId : 1, vendorId : 1, venueId : 1}
```

I am calling proc

```
sequelize.query(
    'call sp_eoi(:param)',
        {replacements: { param: [ { custId:1 , vendorId: 1,venueId : 1  } ] }})
        .spread(function(outputValue , records) {
            console.log(records);        
    }).error(function(err){
        res.json(err);
    });
```

But there is always the error as "Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value {custId: ..}

I am totally new to this and have been trying to find the problem for the last two days.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `param: [ '{ custId:1 , vendorId: 1,venueId : 1  }' ]`?..

Comment: Tried now, now the error is Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "call"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late for the party... however:

**td; dr;**

Postgres uses functions (you can call them stored procedures), but it does not `CALL` them, it `SELECT` them

Here's the link to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38115374/1163927