# How to call procedure in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-oracledb

tell me, please, how I can call this procedure on sequelize

```
declare
p_id_equip number := 123;
p_fil_id   number := 2;
p_errcode  number;
p_errtxt   varchar2(4000);
p_mode     number := 3;
p_is_pool  number := 1;
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  dtd.csm_migrate(p_id_equip => p_id_equip,
              p_fil_id => p_fil_id,
              p_errcode => p_errcode,
              p_errtxt => p_errtxt,
              p_mode => p_mode,
              p_is_pool => p_is_pool);
end;
```

In DBeawer I write

```
CALL CSM_MIGRATE(19659,171,?,?,1,0);
```

and answer OK. I got ERRCODE

BUT in Nodejs
I trying all code from this [Calling stored procedures in Sequelize.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280785/calling-stored-procedures-in-sequelize-js)
but I got errors

```
const result = await sequelize.query(`CALL DTD.CSM_MIGRATE(:19659,:171,?,?,:1,:0);`);
```

doesn't give me a good answer. I don't need this answer.

this code is giving me errors. Because I don't know how to convey ? to params

```
    sequelize
    .query('CALL DTD.CSM_MIGRATE (:id_equip, :fil_id, :errcode, :errtxt, :mode, :is_pool)', 
          {replacements: { id_equip: 19659, fil_id: 171, errcode: ?, errtxt: ?, mode: 1, is_pool: 0}})
    .then(v=>console.log(v));
```

Summary:
how to call this procedure and get ERRCODE?
I apologize for my stupid mistakes :-)

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @Dhaval oracle sql

Answer (score 0):

oups. Here is mistake
`const result = await sequelize.query('CALL DTD.CSM_MIGRATE(:19659,:171,?,?,:1,:0);');`
just one of many failed attempts

I trying
`const result = await dbCSM.fn('CALL DTD.CSM_MIGRATE(19659,171,?,?,1,0);');`

and my result is `Fn { fn: 'CALL DTD.CSM_MIGRATE(19659,171,?,?,1,0);', args: [] }`

Comment: I did IT. Closed